# Spark button ... labelfunction w/ 2 diff. font sizes

Tags: apache-flex

I have a ButtonBar w/ a series of buttons that will each have a custom label:

1. Person's name (fontsize 18)
2. Person's address (fontsize 12)

I am using Flex 4 w/ a custom-skinned spark buttonbar.

I've got the following but how do I now change the fontsizes? Do I change this label function or is that somehow controlled in the spark skin?

'

```
  protected function customLabel(item:Object):String {
    return item.name+ "\n" + item.address;
}
```

'

Comment: I guess another option would be to have 2 different labels: 1 w/ the person's name & a second w/ their address. I have no idea where to even start w/ that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A labelFunction's purpose is to return a string that can be used by the component as a display string for the item in question.  labelFunction has no relation to how the data is displayed.

I did not believe any Flex Components support different fontsizes.  I would look into creating your own custom component that uses two separate labels; one for each font size.  You can probably extend the Button class easy enough to make this happen, adding a new skin part and create a custom skin class that deal with the font sizes and positioning.

Comment: I don't think that only a custom skin is going to do it.  You also need a custom button so that you can have two different labels.  Conceptually, extend the Button Class; add a new skinPart, create a custom skin for that class.  Point the ButtonBar button factory's at your new button class.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ButtonBar.html#top

Comment: I wouldn't call it trivial, but the complication level depends how familiar you are with the Flex Component LifeCycle and building Spark component.  I would recommend that any Flex Developer learn the component lifecycle by heart.